# Python simple number comparison

Tags: python, if-statement, random, comparison

The problem:

The computer randomly generates a number. The user inputs a number, and the computer will tell you if you are too high, or too low. Then you will get to keep guessing until you guess the number.

My solution:

```
import random

computer = random.randint(1, 500)

def guessNumber():      
    user = raw_input('> ')
    while user != computer:
            if user > computer:
                print "Your number is too big"
                user = raw_input('> ')
            else:
                    print "Naa! too small. Try a bit higher number"
                    user = raw_input('> ')
     print "Now the numbers are equal"
```

Unfortunately, my code never run pass the if statement and even with that that it always prints "Your number is too big" even if I enter '1' for user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a *string* value. Turn it into an integer first:

```
user = int(raw_input('> '))
```

Since Python 2 sorts numbers before strings, always, your `user > computer` test will always return True, no matter what was entered:

```
>>> '' > 0
True
```

Python 3 rectifies this:

```
>>> '' > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Note that if the user does not enter a valid number, `int()` will throw a `ValueError`:

```
>>> int('42')
42
>>> int('fortytwo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fortytwo'
```

You may want to explicitly handle that:

```
def askForNumber():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input('> '))
        except ValueError:
            print "Not a number, please try again"


def guessNumber():
    user = askForNumber()
    while user != computer:
        if user > computer:
            print "Your number is too big"
            user = askForNumber()
        else:
            print "Naa! too small. Try a bit higher number"
            user = askForNumber()
    print "Now the numbers are equal"
```

Comment: turning the 'raw_input()' into an integer alone didn't solve my problem but when I handled it explicitly as per your 'askForNumber()' function it worked. I'm trying to understand why but I can't. Even though I prefer your solution, shouldn't it have worked  without the use of the 'askForNumber()' function?

Comment: It should have worked just fine; did you fix *all* `raw_input()` calls?

Comment: sorry that was my bad.. I left the last call out..It works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

your `user` variable is string type because `raw_input()` returns string, change your code like:

```
user = int(raw_input('> '))
```

So `user` would be integer.